# Trouble with adding WFS features in ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, wfs

I add the following WFS address to ArcCatalog just fine and the different feature classes show up in ArcCatalog.  However, when I attempt to drag or add a feature into the TOC of ArcMap, it gives me a "This dataset appears to be invalid" error and the feature gets added to the TOC but is empty with no feature records.

Could I be missing a step here?  I'm using ArcGIS 10.1.  Here is the WFS address:

```
http://ogi.state.ok.us/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&
```

Comment: I tried adding it in ArcMap 10 SP 4, and I didn't see any layers listed with the Service at that URL

Comment: @Roy  So you went into Connection Properties after right-clicking the *.fdl file under Interoperability Connections and clicked "Settings"(Parameter button in 10.1) button and don't see list of features under the Constraints>Feature Types button?

Comment: Sorry about that, I added it as a WMS -- I'm able to add layers from the WFS through interoperability connections.

Comment: Yep, it can be added thru interoperability connections.  So do you get the same error and empty feature class when trying to add a layer to ArcMap?

Comment: I didn't have an error message, I tried one of each vector data type and everything went smoothly.  Maybe it's something that hasn't been ironed out in the pre-release for 10.1?

Comment: I have the same problem. ArcMap 10.1 release version. @wilbev: did you find an answer?

Comment: It seems to be fixed with the final release of 10.1 since it works fine for me now.  I did notice it still seems to error out if you attempt to add more than one feature type layer.

Comment: I have got same problem....I tried adding via interoperability connections, the file is added to the TOC but empty. I know that this layer contains more than 10,000 features, is this the problem? I have done same thing for other layer around 5000 features, they are all ok. So, is there anywhere I have to mention feature number....?

Comment: Feature number could be limited by the WFS provider as well. I had a similar problem some time ago. It was not solvable from my side. If 5000 feature works, but 10000 doesn´t I would guess that this is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

In this case I think the problem is to do with the configuration of the WFS service, not with ArcGIS.

The Service URL is:

```
http://ogi.state.ok.us/geoserver/wfs?
```

And the GetCapabilities request is like below:

```
http://ogi.state.ok.us/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities&
```

or if you specify a version number like:

```
http://ogi.state.ok.us/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities&version=1.1.0&
```

If you add the service URL to ArcCatalog, it will make a request like one of the GetCapabilities requests (above) and you will see the list of operations and available Features.

Take a look however at the response of these GetCapabilities requests, it tells us that to do a GetFeature (and other) request(s) we need to use a different URL

```
<ows:Operation name="GetFeature">
  <ows:DCP>
    <ows:HTTP>
     <ows:Get xlink:href="http://204.62.18.180:8080/geoserver/wfs"/> 
     <ows:Post xlink:href="http://204.62.18.180:8080/geoserver/wfs"/>  
   </ows:HTTP>
 </ows:DCP>
```

So now in ArcMap a request is made to the location referenced in the GetCapabilities response (this is the correct behaviour), but the `http://204.62.18.180:8080/geoserver/wfs` URL does not appear to be publicly available, so no features are returned.